# Getting permission error with service account for Google My Business (GMB), unsure if permissions or code is incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth

OK so my problem is that I am trying to query GMB, I am just trying to get a response back so I'm trying to run a get call.  However, I am getting "The caller does not have permission [403]".  I am unsure why this would be so maybe I am doing something incorrectly.

I created a Service Account with "Owner" privileges, took the .p12 key from it and that's what I'm using in the code as well using that account's email address in the code for serviceAccountEmail.  I am using a Service Account bc I just want to use GMB's location API [Location Data](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/location-data) so I don't need to connect to any users. Any help would be great! Thanks!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("====================");
        try
        {
            new Program().Run().Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private async Task Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GMB API - Location Data");
        Console.WriteLine("==========================");

        String serviceAccountEmail = "test@test-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage" }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new MyBusinessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {

            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        });

        var accountsListRequest = service.Accounts.List();
        ListAccountsResponse accountsResult = accountsListRequest.Execute();

        var account = service.Accounts.Get("accounts/12345").Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Serice accounts need to be preauthorized. Take the service account email address go to GMB share the account with the service account using the email address like you would share it with any other user.

The service account will then have access to the GMB in question

This is assuming that you are sure GMB even supports service accounts which I wasn't aware that it did

seeing as the documentation only appears to mention oauth2 i suspect it still doesn't and you should switch to using oauth2

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup

Comment: This isn't for a calendar API so I'm not sure what calendar you are talking about.  I am trying to use the Location API data that comes from Google My Business and I'm trying to use a service account to call the API since this is Google server data and I would therefore think that this just need 2OL since there's no client in this situation. Yet, I am having issues trying to connect using this account or any other I try to make.

Comment: where did you read that this API supports service accounts?  can you link me that page?

Comment: Well I figured that, because there is no client here, that using service account should work because it's just me trying to get the information about the Google accounts. I also saw this here but maybe I am misinterpreting. Thank you for trying to help, I appreciate it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/my-business-api/Z1_0jM89ZUA

Comment: What do you mean share the account with the server account?  How would I do that?  Again, this isn't a calendar so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: service accounts must be pre-authorized so you need to be able to share your GMB account with it which to my knowledge you can't.   if you have issues with calendar API you should open another question your current question dosent state anything about that